# "Connection closed" error when using vinagre

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, arch-linux

I currently have two machines that I'm trying to connect on a local network.

The problem is this: one machine is running Arch Linux, and the other is running Ubuntu 11.04. I want to remote desktop from Arch Linux to Ubuntu using `vinagre`, but whenever I try to connect, I get a `Connection to host X closed` message.

I can ssh from one to the other and vice-versa, and I have been able to remote into the destination machine using another Ubuntu machine. The machine is configured to allow any connections.

Any ideas as to what might be the culprit? Thanks!